# Bilingualism and cognitive decline (or dementia risk)

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, language, aging

There's apparently a [fairly contested](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4401609/) research area of bilingualism being neuroprotective against cognitive decline in old age, such as dementia.

What are the main points for and against this hypothesis?

Comment: Cognitive decline may be better correlated with diet. See Steven Gundry's *The Plant Paradox*.

Comment: Could you shortly summarize what you already know based on the linked article?

Comment: @AliceD: yes, I will, but I need work on it a little beforehand, because it's easier to refute a point than to provide a somewhat balanced summary.